# How to insert keyframes for the vertices using python

Tags: python, mesh, keyframes

I want to make a specific animation and for this I was thinking in create a mesh and then vary the position of its vertices using a python script, but I don't know how add vertices keyframes on python. Someone can help me?

Comment: Hello ! For meshes this feature is called shape keys. Maybe you can get more information there https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96887/how-to-move-the-keyframes-for-specified-shape-keys-with-python?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keyframe the coordinates of a mesh's vertices similar to how you can keyframe a mesh's location. If 'v' is a vertex of a mesh, you can use `v.keyframe_insert("co", frame = some_number)` .

This is very similar to how if 'obj' is some object, you can keyframe its location using `obj.keyframe_insert("location", frame = some_number)`

Here is a great example of a mesh vertex transformation. It's a stereographic projection homeomorphism. First add a sphere to the scene and make sure it's named 'Sphere'. Then go into edit mode, click on the north pole, and delete the north pole. Next, run the following script.

```
import bpy

sphere = bpy.data.objects["Sphere"]

verts = sphere.data.vertices

# iterate through the vertices of a punctured sphere
for v in verts:
    # keyframe the initial position of each vertex
    v.keyframe_insert("co", frame = 1)
    
    # store the x, y, and z coordinates into variables x, y, and z
    x = v.co.x
    y = v.co.y
    z = v.co.z
    
    # change the position of the vertex coordinate based on a stereographic projection function
    v.co = (2*x/(1 - z), 2*y/(1 - z), -1)
    
    # keyframe the final position of each vertex
    v.keyframe_insert("co", frame = 180)
```