# How to convert "global vertex animation" into different actions by frames

Tags: animation, vertices, keyframes, actions

I have a composite model (consists of many objects).
Each individual object is animated as described in this post: [How to insert keyframes for the vertices using python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/283025/how-to-insert-keyframes-for-the-vertices-using-python)

As a result, I have 1 "global animation" 3k+ frames long, which includes many "actions".
That is, from frame 0 to frame 25 - the action "Stand",
from 25 frames to 75 - "Idle"

How can I use a python script to split a global animation into several actions using pointers to the beginning and end of the frame?

Attach the [*.blend file on GoogleDrive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FwQy-5wa3MH9Nsytztr0JEHqKX80curr/view?usp=sharing). Maybe it can help to understand me.

(sry, just noob)